# Divs shrinking too much upon resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my site fluid/responsive. When you start to decrease the size of the browser, just before I have my first @media query, the three 
divs (vd-grid-sub-box) shrink too much leaving a big gap between them and the footer. I really don't understand how to correct this. Everything should be shrinking proportionally without creating bigger gaps.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

/*Vivid Global Styling*/

html {} body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
li,
span {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.wht {
  color: #fff;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/*Vivid Page Settings*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: #000 1px solid;
}
.vd-hide {
  display: none;
}
.vd-settings-wrapper {
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.vd-user-settings {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 0 21px;
}
.vd-currency-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 1px 2px;
}
.vd-language-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 2px 0 2px;
}
/*Vivid Main Navigation*/

.vd-nav-wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  height: 78px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper ul {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 18px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-logo-img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/*Vivid Checkout Settings*/

.vd-cart-wrapper {
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.vd-cart-selector {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: -11px 31px 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: -9px;
}
/*Vivid Main Wrapper*/

.vd-page-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Vivid Grid*/

.vd-grid h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
}
.vd-grid p,
span {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.vd-grid h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.vd-grid h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid h3 {
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid h4 {
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid {
  width: 98.6%;
  margin: 13px auto;
}
.vd-grid-left-col {
  width: 77.6%;
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.vd-grid-right-col {
  width: 20.8%;
  float: left;
}
.vd-grid-main-box {
  width: 93.5%;
  height: 460px;
  background-color: #000029;
  padding: 3.2%;
}
.vd-grid-main-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.vd-grid-sub-box {
  width: 30.8%;
  height: 185px;
  background-image: url(../img/granda_hj.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  background-color: #000029;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.9%;
  margin: 0 0 1% 0.2%;
}
.vd-grid-xtra-box {
  width: 94%;
  height: 347px;
  background-image: url(../img/tst_img.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #000029;
  padding: 3%;
}
.vd-text-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 340px;
  left: 0px;
}
.vd-margin-top {
  margin-top: 4%;
}
.vd-margin-right {
  /*! margin-right:10px; */
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.vd-margin-left {
  /*! margin-left:10px; */
  margin-left: 0.8%;
}
.vd-margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
/*Vivid Footer*/

.vd-footer {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  background-color: #000029;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), -webkit-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), -moz-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}
.vd-widget-area {
  padding: 15px 0 10px;
  border-top: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto 0px;
}
.vd-footer-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 26%;
  padding-right: 60px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.vd-footer-links {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 30px 25px 0;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
.vd-footer-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: outside none;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.vd-footer-links li {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vd-footer-links a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vd-footer-links a:hover {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
.vd-footer-title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.vd-signup {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 305px;
  width: 26%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.vd-sub-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding-top: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Vivid Payment Icons*/

.vd-payment-icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #a7a7a7;
}
.vd-footer-linklist .vd-social-icon:before {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: 'Social Icons';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.vd-payment-options {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  list-style: outside none;
}
.vd-payment-options ul {
  display: block-inline;
  list-style-type: outside none;
}
.vd-payment-options li {
  display: block-inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  list-style-type: outside none;
}
.american-express:before {
  content: "\f001";
}
.bitcoin:before {
  content: "\f006";
}
.jcb:before {
  content: "\f028";
}
.master:before {
  content: "\f02d";
}
.paypal:before {
  content: "\f033";
}
.visa:before {
  content: "\f045";
}
/*Vivid Copyright*/

.vd-copyright-wrapper {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.vd-grid-sub-box vd-margin-right vd-margin-left {

 margin-left: 100px;
}
/*Vivid Responsive*/

@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.6/2),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min-resolution: 1.3dppx) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 928px) {
  .vd-grid-left-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .vd-grid-right-col {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 99%;
    margin-bottom: -2%;
    margin-top: -0.5%;
    clear: both;
  }
  .vd-grid-right-col > div {
    width: 49%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .vd-grid-right-col > div:first-child {
    margin-right: 0.5%;
  }
  .vd-grid-xtra-box {
    float: left;
  }
  .vd-footer{
    margin-top: 20px;  
  }

  li {
   font-size: 10px;
  }

  .vd-hide {

   display: inline-block;
  }

  .vd-nav-wrapper ul {

   display: none;
  }




@media screen and (max-width: 490px) {

    .vd-grid-sub-box {

        width: 100%;
    }

    .vd-currency-selector {

     display: none;
    }

    .vd-language-selector {

     display: none;
    }


    .vd-grid-right-col > div {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    float: none;
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<title>Vivid Shop Display</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="menu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='css/vivid-style.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/scroller.css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<header>
<div class="vd-navigation-wrapper">
     <div class="vd-settings-wrapper">
     <div class="vd-user-settings">
        </div>
        <div class="vd-currency-selector">
        </div>
        <div class="vd-language-selector">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="vd-nav-wrapper">
   <ul>
    <li>Shop</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li class="vd-logo-img"><img src="img/vivid_logo.png"/></li>
    <li>Lookbook</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
   </ul>
     </div>
      <div class="vd-cart-wrapper">
       <div class="vd-cart-selector"></div>
      </div>
      
</div>




<!--Mobile Navigation-->
  <nav class="vd-hide">
  <div class="menuIcon">
    <a href="#menuExpand">Menu</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <a class="nav toggle-menu" href="#">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </a>
  </div>
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="#firstSection"><img src="img/harva_logo.png"/></a></h1>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li data-menuanchor="firstSection">
        <a href="#firstSection" title="First Section">First Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="secondSection">
        <a href="#secondSection" title="Second Section">Second Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="thirdSection">
        <a href="#thirdSection" title="Second Section">Third Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fourthSection">
        <a href="#fourthSection" title="Fourth Section">Fourth Section</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection">
        <a href="#fifthSection" title="First Slide">First Slide</a>
      </li>
      <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection/1">
        <a href="#fifthSection/1" title="Second Slide">Second Slide</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
<!--End Mobile Navigation-->

<div class="vd-page-container">
 <div class="vd-grid">
  <div class="vd-grid-left-col">
  <div class="vd-grid-main-box vd-margin-bottom">
     <div class="vd-text-wrap">
     <h1>Header Text</h1>
        <h2>Secondary Title</h2>
        <p>Featured Text Here over two lines
if needed place here.</p>
</div>
    </div>

    <div class="vd-grid-sub-box">
     <h3>Header Text</h3>
        <p>Featured Text Here over two lines
if needed place here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-grid-sub-box vd-margin-right vd-margin-left">
        <h3>Header Text</h3>
        <p>Featured Text Here over two lines
if needed place here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-grid-sub-box">
        <h3>Header Text</h3>
        <p>Featured Text Here over two lines
if needed place here.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="vd-grid-right-col vd-margin-left">
     <div class="vd-grid-xtra-box">
      <h4>Header Text</h4>
      <p>Featured Text Here over two lines
if needed place here.</p>
     </div>
      <div class="vd-grid-xtra-box vd-margin-top vd-margin-bottom">
     <h4>Header Text</h4>
      <p>Featured Text Here over two lines
if needed place here.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
    <footer class="vd-footer">
     <div class="vd-widget-area">
        <div class="vd-footer-text">
            <h4 class="vd-footer-title">V I V I D - SHOPIFY THEME</h4>
          <div class="rte">V I V I D is a customisable theme that looks and feels fantastic. Showcase your products on the visually stunning V I V I D Grid and choose your structure then let V I V I D do the rest!</div>
        </div>
          <div class="vd-footer-links">
              <h4 class="vd-footer-title">HELP</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="" href="#">HELP | FAQ'S</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">RETURNS</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">HOW TO SHOP</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">STOCKISTS</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
         <div class="vd-footer-links">
          <h4 class="vd-footer-title">POLICIES</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="" href="#">DELIVERY &amp; RETURNS POLICY</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">TERMS &amp; CONDITIONS</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#">SECURITY POLICY</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    <div class="vd-footer-links">
         <h4 class="vd-footer-title">CONNECT</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="vd-social-icon facebook" href="#" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                <li><a class="vd-social-icon twitter" href="#" target="_blank">TWITTER</a></li>
                <li><a class="vd-social-icon instagram" href="#" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                <li><a class="vd-social-icon vimeo" href="#" target="_blank">VIMEO</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <div class="vd-signup">
            <h4 class="vd-footer-title">SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h4>
          <div class="wht">HTML Block to be added here for embedded email capture forms</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="vd-sub-footer">
      <ul class="vd-payment-options">
          <li class="vd-payment-icon american-express"></li>
          <li class="vd-payment-icon bitcoin"></li>
          <li class="vd-payment-icon jcb"></li> 
          <li class="vd-payment-icon master"></li>
          <li class="vd-payment-icon paypal"></li>
          <li class="vd-payment-icon visa"></li> 
      </ul>
    <div class="vd-copyright-wrapper">
      <p class="vd-copyright">Copyright © 2017 V I V I D Themes.</p>
      <p class="vd-attribution">"Virtual Visual Merchandising"</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.vd-grid-sub-box vd-margin-right vd-margin-left {...` selects nothing

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I've got an element with class `<div class="vd-grid-sub-box vd-margin-right vd-margin-left">` so css selector for it should look like: `.vd-grid-sub-box.vd-margin-right.vd-margin-left` not like `.vd-grid-sub-box vd-margin-right vd-margin-left`

Comment: Ah, okay I understand. I still don't understand why the gap between the footer and the three divs (vd-grid-sub-box) increase when I start shrinking my browser.

Comment: as I can see, there are too much mess in your code associated with `flex` using. If I would develop this structure, I'd use twitter-bootstrap. That would be made much easier and faster along with clear code readability